# Pass Array using AJAX in Django

Tags: django, ajax, django-views

I have an array called metrics and im trying to pass it to backend with AJAX but Im only getting the last values of the array `7,8,9` . I want to pick up the whole array .Any idea how? Any help is appreciated.

**html**

```
 var metrics = [
  [1,2,3],
  [4,5,6],
  [7,8,9], 
];

 $.ajax({
        type : 'GET' , 
        url : "...",
        data : {"metrics[]": metrics },
    })
```

**views.py**

```
def Sensor_Metrics(request):
    if request.is_ajax and request.method == "GET" : 
        metrics = request.GET.get("metrics[]")
        print(metrics)
    return JsonResponse({"error": ""}, status=400)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the views, you need to use `request.GET.getlist` in order to get the complete list from the request.
You need to use -: `metrics = request.GET.getlist("metrics[]")`. You can refer the docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/request-response/#:%7E:text=QueryDict.update(other_dict)%C2%B6).

Answer (score 1):

**The solution is adding the brackets in `views.py` while calling the request.**

in script

```
 var metrics = [
  [1,2,3],
  [4,5,6],
  [7,8,9], 
];

 $.ajax({
        type : 'GET' , 
        url : "...",
        data : {"metrics": metrics},
    })
```

in views.py

```
def Sensor_Metrics(request):
    if request.is_ajax and request.method == "GET" : 
        metrics = request.GET.get("metrics[]") #Important
        print(metrics)
    return JsonResponse({"error": ""}, status=400)
```